# Updating probabilities given new information

Tags: probability

In a race of hare, bird and tortoise, the animals have respective probabilities 75%, 20%, and 5% of winning. A computer tries to guess the winner of the race by picking one animal at random, with equal probabilities. What is the probability that the computer guesses correctly?

- I understand that this probability is one-third by writing $P(C) =
     P(\text{choose hare}\ | \ \text{hare wins})\,P(\text{hare wins}) +
     \cdots$ but I don't see the intuition behind it. I believe the issue
  is conditional independence, but I can't seem to isolate what the
  events are and which is independent of which?

Previously the probability that any particular animal was chosen was 1/3. Now if we’re given that the winner was chosen, the probability that bird was chosen decreases to 20% - exactly the odds of bird winning. However, the corresponding probability increases for the hare. I can’t see an intuitive explanation for this fact. Is it because hare was most likely to win, or more likely to win than the bird, or more likely to win than that it was chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer backs a winner if it picks one of the animals and that animal wins.

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \mathsf P\big((C=h \cap W=h)\cup(C=t\cap W=t)\cup (C=b\cap W=b)\big)$$

These events are *disjoint* , also known as *mutually exclusive*.    Only one animal can win (assuming all ties are resolved).

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \mathsf P(C=h \cap W=h)+\mathsf P(C=t\cap W=t)+\mathsf P(C=b\cap W=b)$$

*Then* we use conditional probabilities

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \mathsf P(C=h\mid W=h)\mathsf P(W=h)+\mathsf P(C=t\mid W=t)\mathsf P(W=t)+\mathsf P(C=b\mid W=b)\mathsf P(W=b)$$

**Now the computer's choice is independent of whom actually wins.**

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \mathsf P(C=h)\mathsf P(W=h)+\mathsf P(C=t)\mathsf P(W=t)+\mathsf P(C=b)\mathsf P(W=b)$$

And the computer's choice is made without bias.

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \tfrac 1 3\mathsf P(W=h)+\tfrac 1 3\mathsf P(W=t)+\tfrac 1 3\mathsf P(W=b)$$

Hence by total probability:

$$\mathsf P(C=W) ~=~ \tfrac 1 3$$

---

> Now if we’re given that the winner was chosen, the probability that bird was chosen decreases to 20% -

Totally different thing.  For this we use

$$\begin{align}P(C=b\mid C=W) ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(C=b\cap C=W)}{\mathsf P(C=W)} \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(C=b\cap W=b)}{\mathsf P(C=W)} \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(C=b\mid W=b)\mathsf P(W=b)}{\mathsf P(C=W)} \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\tfrac 1 3 \mathsf P(W=b)}{\tfrac 1 3} \\[1ex]~=~&\mathsf P(W=b)\end{align}$$

In words: The probability that the computer choose the bird when given that the computer choose the winner, is equal to the probability that the bird is the winner.